# Which are the steps for crafting an Celestial (Exotic) armor?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In Guild Wars 2, there are armors with a `Celestial` bonus (which have all stats as a bonus), which were introduced some time ago, during an event. I know those are still craftable, but i can't seem to find an organized step-by-step guide to craft an Celestial Ascended piece of armor.

Also, as a bonus, i would like a "Price Comparison" to craft an Exotic Celestial Armor vs a Ascended Celestial Armor (assuming the character already has a leve 500 Armorsmith)

Comment: Which armor weight are you looking to craft?

Comment: Nevermind, I noticed that you wrote level 500 Armorsmith, so you're probably making heavy armor, but I'm writing my answer to cover all three types.

Comment: I finished writing my answer. Sorry for the delay, it took a bit of research to get all the numbers right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Exotic

**Important**: This requires [Armorsmith](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Armorsmith), [Leatherworker](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Leatherworker), or [Tailor](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Tailor) crafting level **400**, depending on which type of armor you want. I will use X / Y / Z format from here on to indicate different values for Armorsmith / Leatherworker / Tailor.

1. Obtain a [Celestial Intricate Gossamer Insignia recipe](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Recipe:_Celestial_Intricate_Gossamer_Insignia) and one recipe for each of the six armor pieces, all of which can be purchased on the trading post. Search for "Celestial" and Draconic / Emblazoned / Exalted.
2. Use those recipes on the appropriate character.
3. You'll now need to gather the materials. Let's start with [Charged Quartz Crystals](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Charged_Quartz_Crystal), because those are the tricky part. You'll need 750 [Quartz Crystals](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Quartz_Crystal) in total, of which you can fuse 25 into one Charged Quartz Crystal (at a "point of power", aka commune skill point challenge) once per day. This means that you'll need at least 30 days to get all of the required materials.
4. Once you have your 30 Charged Quartz Crystals, you'll need to refine your raw crafting materials to craft 6 [Celestial Intricate Gossamer Insignias](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Celestial_Intricate_Gossamer_Insignia) and the tier 6 (Orichalcum / Hardened / Gossamer) crafting components for one of each piece of armor.

   This will require the following materials:

   - 30 Charged Quartz Crystals
   - 30 [Globs of Ectoplasm](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Glob_of_Ectoplasm)
   - 130 [Spools of Gossamer Thread](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Spool_of_Gossamer_Thread)
   - 74 / 72 / 96 [Gossamer Scraps](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Gossamer_Scrap)
   - 32 / 0 / 0 [Orichalcum Ore](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Orichalcum_Ore)
   - 0 / 36 / 12 [Hardened Leather Sections](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Hardened_Leather_Section)

### Ascended

**Important**: This requires [Armorsmith](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Armorsmith), [Leatherworker](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Leatherworker), or [Tailor](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Tailor) crafting level **500**, depending on which type of armor you want. I will use X / Y / Z format from here on to indicate different values for Armorsmith / Leatherworker / Tailor.

1. Obtain a [Celestial Intricate Gossamer Insignia recipe](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Recipe:_Celestial_Intricate_Gossamer_Insignia) (unless you already unlocked it to craft your exotic armor).
2. Purchase and use an [Ascended Insignia recipe](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Recipe:_Ascended_Insignia) from the master craftsman. Select "Recipe: Wupwup Celestial Insignia" from the list. Then purchase and use each of the six ascended armor piece recipes from the last tab of the master craftsman. Use each of those, selecting the "WupWup" option for each.
3. Consume all of the above recipes on the appropriate character.
4. (same as exotic step #3 above)
5. Once you have your 30 Charged Quartz Crystals, you'll need to refine your raw crafting materials to craft 6 [Celestial Intricate Gossamer Insignias](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Celestial_Intricate_Gossamer_Insignia), which you will then use to craft six [Wupwup Celestial Insignias](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Wupwup_Celestial_Insignia). You will also need to craft Ectoplasm Refinement materials, which are limited to one per day, but you can bypass the time gate by buying the refined materials. You'll finally need to craft tier 7 (Deldrimor Steel / Elonian / Damask) crafting components for one of each piece of armor.

   This will require the following materials. The ones marked with a * can be bought on the trading post to bypass the time gated materials required to craft them.

   - 30 Charged Quartz Crystals
   - 30 [Globs of Ectoplasm](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Glob_of_Ectoplasm)
   - 30 [Globs of Dark Matter](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Glob_of_Dark_Matter)
   - 120 [Piles of Crystalline Dust](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Pile_of_Crystalline_Dust)
   - 6 [Augur's Stones](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Augur%27s_Stone)
   - 1500 [Piles of Bloodstone Dust](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Pile_of_Bloodstone_Dust)
   - 1500 [Empyreal Fragments](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Empyreal_Fragment)
   - 1500 [Dragonite Ore](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Dragonite_Ore)
   - 150 [Thermocatalytic Reagents](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Thermocatalytic_Reagent)
   - 480 [Spools of Gossamer Thread](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Spool_of_Gossamer_Thread)
   - 60 / 60 / 60 [Gossamer Scraps](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Gossamer_Scrap)
   - 16 / 0 / 0 [Deldrimor Steel Ingots](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Deldrimor_Steel_Ingot)*
   - 0 / 18 / 5 [Elonian Leather Squares](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Elonian_Leather_Square)*
   - 25 / 24 / 36 [Bolts of Damask](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Bolt_of_Damask)*

   If you are not looking to bypass the time gate, here are the total materials for **each** refined ascended material.

   Deldrimor Steel Ingot:

   - 1 Glob of Ectoplasm
   - 10 Thermocatalytic Reagents
   - 100 [Mithril Ore](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mithril_Ore)
   - 90 [Iron Ore](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Iron_Ore)
   - 10 [Lumps of Coal](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Lump_of_Coal)
   - 40 [Platinum Ore](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Platinum_Ore)
   - 20 [Lumps of Primordium](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Lump_of_Primordium)

   Elonian Leather Square:

   - 1 Glob of Ectoplasm
   - 10 Thermocatalytic Reagents
   - 150 [Thick Leather Sections](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Thick_Leather_Section)
   - 40 [Thin Leather Sections](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Thin_Leather_Section)
   - 20 [Coarse Leather Sections](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Coarse_Leather_Section)
   - 40 [Rugged Leather Sections](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Rugged_Leather_Section)

   Bolt of Damask:

   - 1 Glob of Ectoplasm
   - 25 Spools of Gossamer Thread
   - 300 [Silk Scraps](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Silk_Scrap)
   - 40 [Wool Scraps](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Wool_Scrap)
   - 20 [Cotton Scraps](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Cotton_Scrap)
   - 40 [Linen Scraps](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Linen_Scrap)

As for a price comparison, it's impossible to be exact. The market fluctuates constantly, so the prices of the materials shift. In terms of [coins](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Coin), ascended armor is many times more expensive than exotic. In addition to the monetary cost, a full set of ascended armor costs 120 [skill points](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Skill_point), and the recipes cost an additional 21,000 [karma](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Karma) and 30 [laurels](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Laurel).

Comment: Best answer ever. Couldn't be more accurate